# How to change font face on TabBarItem?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion and I need to set a custom font to the tabBarItems. I use this code and I get no errors but the font face is not changing either.

```
tabBarController.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes({UITextAttributeFont => UIFont.fontWithName('Futura-Medium', size:17)}, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    [yourTabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-Medium" size:17.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: forgive me, i don't have any knowledge about Ruby language.

Answer (score 0):

Literally translated, this becomes:

```
yourTabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes(
  NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys(
      UIColor.whiteColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
      NSValue.valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,0), UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
      UIFont.fontWithName("Futura-Medium", size:17.0), UITextAttributeFont, nil
      ),
    forState:UIControlStateNormal)
```

I haven't tried the code, but one might presume that instead of the NSDictionary, you could use a Ruby hash, thereby eliminating some of the Objective-C'ness:

```
yourTabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes(
  {
      UITextAttributeTextColor:        UIColor.whiteColor,
      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: NSValue.valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,0), 
      UITextAttributeFont:             UIFont.fontWithName("Futura-Medium", size:17.0)
  },
  forState:UIControlStateNormal)
```

Again, I haven't tried this, but it's a literal translation, with a little Motion thrown in of the Objective-C version.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Futura-Medium` included by default on iOS?  If not, toss it in `resources/`